# How do I enable Deep linking in WebAssembly for Uno Platform

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

Any clue or direction to implement URL deep linking in Uno Platform for WebAssembly?

I saw it is implemented in following projects that can be found on https://platform.uno/showcases/

Projects:

- https://www.troublefreepool.com/blog/poolmath/
- https://www.biyee.net/default.aspx

Comment: This question was focused enough, and should not be closed. It is asking on how to do deeplinking, that's the focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deep linking can be done through the `LaunchActivatedEventArgs.Arguments` of the `Application.OnLaunched` method override.

You'll find the query string part of the browser's current address, so for :

`https://example.com/?test=1234&test2=5678`

You'll get:

`test=1234&test2=5678`